# Typescript map and find function usage

Tags: typescript

I have array list of interface. I want to get the element Properties[1] based on   element Properties[0] data. I have implemented this by using  map and find function at 2 statement.
I also adjusted noimplictreturn variable as false at tsconfig. ( for map and find function )
I need to get

```
{
      "Key": "Value",
       "Value": "30",
 }
```

as a result from A2[] array in  below code. I used both map and find, can I implement this with more efficent way?

```
interface A1 {
  Key: string,
  Value : string
};

interface A2 {
  Properties: A1[],  
  Name: string
};

 
var arrayInterface : A2[] = [ 
    {
       
        "Properties": [
            {
                "Key": "Key",
                "Value": "Band",
               
            },
            {
                "Key": "Value",
                "Value": "30",
               
            }
        ],       
        "Name": "AAA"         
    },
    {       
        "Properties": [
            {
                "Key": "Key",
                "Value": "Cup"
                
            },
            {
                "Key": "Value",
                "Value": "A"                  
            }
        ],   
        "Name": "BBB"            
    }];
   

 let found;
    
 found= arrayInterface.map(function (x) 
 {
              if (x.Properties[0].Value == 'Band') { return x.Properties[1] };
 });

console.log( found);
    
 found=  found.find(function (item) {
            if (item != undefined) {return item.Key == "Value"};
 });
    
 console.log( find);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a single `find()` operation should be sufficient:

```
interface A1 {
  Key: string,
  Value : string
};

interface A2 {
  Properties: A1[],  
  Name: string
};

const data: A2[] = [{
  "Properties": [{
    "Key": "Key",
    "Value": "Band",

  }, {
    "Key": "Value",
    "Value": "30",

  }],
  "Name": "AAA"
}, {
  "Properties": [{
    "Key": "Key",
    "Value": "Cup"

  }, {
    "Key": "Value",
    "Value": "A"
  }],
  "Name": "BBB"
}];

const res = data.find((v) => v.Properties[0]?.Value === 'Band')?.Properties[1];

console.log(res);
```

---

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIEZkG8CwAoZZAaQgE8AuZAZzClAHMAafQgNTgBsBXFSmukPXwBfANz58oSLEQpUAJmwtkABSgB7AA7QwwCFUoYA2gF1GhZQDk4AWwh9aDEeLz4E6kDWQATOGDiG8qbIALzIRrgEyABEalo6elTRlBHKhNEkpMkxmdHMUens3BDZ0QBCcCDeeRJRwuaRhOm5lNFFPDUFMe0lrQDMAAydysJmytHWdqWoM9EiDeNx2lC6+tmpXRlkpbn5Td2cHa0Awlyac651C5stB8Wd+22HvTGoF4SjezGTL+VlZRdRi43B4vFB9KEfH44AA6GCgbwACkRADcAJShAB8yBRMKWCX0RgGJgA-DCeqEQmEAOQVKrUtFk-ErRJGdAmYF4dyedQcCAwjjqeiI8FUNEuIA)</sup>

Comment: exactly this is working incredibly too.

Answer (score 1):

For possible multiple results you can use:

```
const results = arrayInterface
  .filter(x => x.Properties[0].Value === 'Band')
  .map(x => x.Properties[1])
  .filter(x => x.Key === 'Value');

console.log(results);
```

Comment: You are incredible!!!

Comment: Just I changed  filter function  to find function  at the end. Because filter returns array , find returns objcet    const results = arrayInterface
  .filter(x => x.Properties[0].Value === 'Band')
  .map(x => x.Properties[1])
  .find(x => x.Key === 'Value');